# How To Grab <a href="url"> Links With No Classes Or ID's with BeautifulSoup4 (Python 2.7)

Tags: python, html

I am struggling trying to grab a  tag that doesn't contain any class or id. It is just the a href, and then the link.

html code - there is more, but this is just a short bit of it. Im trying to grab the a href="url is here", but I can't just grab "a" because it will grab every link on the page.

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr class="">
<td class="col1 align">
<a href="url is here">
1
</a>
</td>
<td class="col2">
<a href="www.example.com">
<img class="avatar" src="www.example.com" alt="le me">
le me
<img class="test" alt="test" title="test"    src="test-icon.png">
</a>
</td>
<td class="col3 align">
<a href="www.example.com">
2,715
</a>
</td>
<td class="col4 align">
<a href="www.example.com">
5,400,000,000
</a>
</td>
</tr>
```

My code:

```
source_code = requests.get(url)
plain_text = source_code.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)
for link in soup.findAll():
    username = link.get()
    print(username)
```

I don't have these filled in because anything I try won't work. Not sure what else to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can select all `a` tags and using the `has_attr` function check if it has the `class` or `id` attributes:

```
for link in soup.findAll('a'):
    if link.has_attr('class') or link.has_attr('id'):
        continue
    username = link.get('href')
    print(username)
```